# after crm 2011 organization import errors

Tags: linq, import, dynamics-crm-2011, organization

I have an organization that is deployed on an IFD CRM. My goal is to import that organization to new farm that has CRM 2011 with no IFD. Everything is ok while importing
but after import I cannot open that organization on new server. The error detail is:

Event code: 3007
Event message: A compilation error has occurred.
Event time: 27.12.2012 03:32:20
Event time (UTC): 27.12.2012 01:32:20
Event ID: 658277a3edea44089ca9af6e0c31f6c4
Event sequence: 236
Event occurrence: 5
Event detail code: 0
Exception message: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config(389):
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

After that error, I created new organizations and there is no problem with that new organization.

The CRM is with update rollup 8.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on crm server side tracing. You'll get much better error information. Use the CRM diagnostic tool to turn on trace logging: http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com.

I'm wondering if you have some plugin associated with the organization.  So when you try to access it, the plugin fires and throws that exception.

Answer (score 0):

You may have plugins in some of your solutions. It maybe configured to use the connections to your previous server. Hence, when you import it some error encountered. This is just a guess! If you provide more information on your error message, then could be analyze it better.